# How to fetch two records from subquery

Tags: mysql

i want to fetch two records from subquery but it gives error below is what u tried

Below works :

```
SELECT id, (SELECT color FROM tblcolor WHERE pid=id) as color FORM maintable
```

Not works

```
SELECT id, (SELECT color,price FROM tblcolor WHERE pid=id) FORM maintable
```

Please help me with solution for it

Comment: subquery return only single column. you need to use `join` for this query.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems like this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.color, t2.price FROM maintable t1 INNER JOIN tblcolor t2 on t1.id = t2.pid
```